# How do I add variables to a module's hook's existing render array and have them available as template variables?

Tags: theming, search

As an example, the [hook_search_execute function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.api.php/function/hook_search_execute/7) returns the following array:

```
$results[] = array(
      'link' => url('node/' . $item->sid, array('absolute' => TRUE)),
      'type' => check_plain(node_type_get_name($node)),
      'title' => $node->title,
      'user' => theme('username', array('account' => $node)),
      'date' => $node->changed,
      'node' => $node,
      'extra' => $extra,
      'score' => $item->calculated_score,
      'snippet' => search_excerpt($keys, $node->body),
    );
```

`'link'` and `'title'` are required and the others are optional. However, what if I wanted to add my element to the array like `'photo'` and then have that available in the $search-result.tpl.php file?

Whe I add that element to the search results array, I indeed see it when I do a dump of $variables in _preprocess_search_result(). If it's available there, then how to I make it available as `<?php print $photo; ?>` in search-result.tpl.php?

Comment: If a variable is added in the preprocess function, it should automatically be available in the corresponding template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [`template_preprocess_search_result`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21search%21search.pages.inc/function/template_preprocess_search_result/7) you have the `$result` variable available, so if you've already injected your custom field into the result you can just use

```
print $result['photo'];
```

In the template file.

Or if you're absolutely set on just having a `$photo` var, you need to add it to the variables for the template:

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_search_result(&$vars) {
  $vars['photo'] = $vars['result']['photo'];
}
```

Comment: so $title, $snippet, etc are predefined somewhere in the system, and elements from that array are not assigned dynamically? I was hoping not to make the assignment twice, but if this is the way to go for extra $variables we'd like to show up in the existing template files, I'm happy with that. Thanks!